# Where is the NewForm.aspx definition in Help Desk application template?

Tags: wss-3.0, 2007

I am trying to hide a field (Customer) from the Help Desk application template for WSS 3.0. There should be a setting for this in the feature definitions but I couldn't find it.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is through SharePoint Designer 2007. Sahil Malik has a good quick runthrough of how to do this:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Customize_the_-and-quot;NewFormaspx-and-quot;_page_for_a_SharePoint_List.aspx

Comment: I can't use this method because of 2 reasons:
1. If I change the default entry form in any way the application starts to show some strange behavior.
2. I have to change the definition because the templates will be used to provision multiple sites. It won't be feasible to change every NewForm.aspx for every site created.